# How to set the status of checkbox inside a listview using simple adapter?

Tags: android, checkbox, android-listview

I am using a listview which has one checkbox and 4 textviews for each list item. I want to fill the list with the stored data. I know how to fill the textviews with data using SimpleAdapter. But I want help on how to predefine the status(checked or not) of checkbox while creating the list.

Using this code I put my text into the textviews. Please tell me whether I can set the status of checkbox in the same way.

```js
        final String LEAVE_ID = "leave_id";
  final String MEMBER_NAME = "member_name";
  final String LEAVE_CODE = "leave_code";
  final String LEAVE_DATE = "leave_date";
  final String CHECK_BOX="check_box";

  //setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

  list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
  HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
  leaveList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view_for_leaves);
  Button clearButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clear_button);
  Button deleteButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delete_button);
  clearButton.setOnClickListener(this);
  deleteButton.setOnClickListener(this);
  
  map = new HashMap<String, String>();
  map.put(LEAVE_ID, "1234");
  map.put(MEMBER_NAME, "Nithin");
  map.put(LEAVE_CODE, "Vacation Leave");
  map.put(LEAVE_DATE, "12-12-14");
  list.add(map);

  map = new HashMap<String, String>();
  map.put(LEAVE_ID, "1232");
  map.put(MEMBER_NAME, "Mithil");
  map.put(LEAVE_CODE, "Sick Leave");
  map.put(LEAVE_DATE, "20-12-14");
  list.add(map);  
  
  adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, list,
    R.layout.list_item_leave, new String[] { LEAVE_ID, MEMBER_NAME,
      LEAVE_CODE, LEAVE_DATE }, new int[] { R.id.leave_id,
      R.id.member_name, R.id.leave_type, R.id.leave_date });
  leaveList.setAdapter(adapter);
  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

```html
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/leave_check"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#dcdcdc" 
        android:checked="false"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/leave_id"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#dcdcdc"
        android:gravity="center"
        
        android:text="@string/project_no"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/member_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#d3d3d3"
        android:gravity="center"
        
        android:text="@string/project_name"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/leave_type"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#dcdcdc"
        android:gravity="center"        
        android:text="@string/type"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/leave_date"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#d3d3d3"
        android:gravity="center"
        
        android:text="@string/client"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</TableRow>
```

Comment: see **SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder** and **SimpleAdapter** docs

Comment: sample is https://www.google.com/search?q=simpleadapter.viewbinder+example&oq=SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0j69i60j0.2271j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8